# Joda-Time Formatter with a dateStyle and a timeStyle

Tags: java, date, datetime, format, jodatime

With [`java.text.DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), it's possible to build a date formatter with a date and a time style :

```
DateFormat df = getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.LONG);
system.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

Is it possible to use something similar with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Standard Formatting Built Into JodaTime

There's a bunch of standard **Date** and **Time** formats built right into **JodaTime**.

Here's an example of one that I use:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);

String formattedDateTime = dateTime.toString(DateTimeFormat.fullDateTime());
```

Notice the `DateTimeFormat.fullDateTime()`.

Some other options for this include:

- `fullTime()`
- `fullDate()`
- `shortDateTime()`
- `forStyle("MS")`  *Indicates a **Medium** Date and a **Short** Time.*
- `forStyle("S-")`  *Indicates a **Short** Date and **No** Time.*
- *... etc ...*

#### The full listing can be found at:

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forStyle(java.lang.String)

Cheers,

JP

Comment: As this correct answer says, Joda-Time offers many ways to format. There are built in styles as shown, there are standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, there are Locale-sensitive formats, and you can [build your own formatters](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) if you have something peculiar in mind. Search StackOverflow for "joda format".

Answer (score -1):

Use DateTimeFormat.forPattern() with a pattern that does what you want.
For instance, `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: I want to use DateTimeFormatter.SHORT because I don't want a static pattern, I need something that will automatically change based on the Locale information